# Get the string name of an anonymous object type?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a common provider for many of my backend controllers that looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class CommonMasterdataProvider<T> {
    private readonly route:string = '/api/';

    constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
        this.route = this.route + T.name; //?? What can I use to get the type name here?
    }
```

I can inject this into my component controllers but it would be nice if I can get the name of the anonymous type name. **Basically I'm looking for the TypeScript version of the c# nameof() operator.** Or a Javascript way but it has to work even after minifying code.

I have tried adding a new string parameter to the constructor but this way the Angular injector thrown an exception that it couldn't find anything for the type String.

Comment: Check out this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata -- it comes with Angular so you should already have it in your project. Seems like it may help with something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, the generic piece (T) does not get transpiled into JavaScript, so it actually does not exist. This means you won't be able to work with T directly, except as an 'interface' so to speak.
Is there a way you can pass an instance of T or the T's constructor to the constructor of CommonMasterdataProvider ? That way you will be able to get the name.